# How to extract the first and last two parts from a string separated by underscore in bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash

So we have a file named like this:

> some-app-name_CT-111-some-title-with_underscore-in-it_c37a9a5fc272a5c94009a61ce8dff79900ab9102_2017-07-24-03-22-19.tar.bz2

As you can see there are 4 parts, a app name (dasherized), a title (that may contain underscore in it), a hash code and finally a timestamp (dasherized)

They are separated by underscore, the problem is that the title may have underscore in it. So how can we get the first part first and then the last two parts (separated by underscore) and then the remain is the title?

Any help is appreciated.

Final parts should be like:

- App name: some-app-name
- Title: CT-111-some-title-with_underscore-in-it
- ID: c37a9a5fc272a5c94009a61ce8dff79900ab9102
- Timestamp: 2017-07-24-03-22-19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bash regex you can do this:

```
s='some-app-name_CT-111-some-title-with_underscore-in-it_c37a9a5fc272a5c94009a61ce8dff79900ab9102_2017-07-24-03-22-19.tar.bz2'

re='^([^_]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)_([a-fA-F0-9]+)_([0-9-]+)\.'

[[ $s =~ $re ]] && printf "AppName: %s\nTitle: %s\nID: %s\nTimestamp: %s\n" \
        "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"

AppName: some-app-name
Title: CT-111-some-title-with_underscore-in-it
ID: c37a9a5fc272a5c94009a61ce8dff79900ab9102
Timestamp: 2017-07-24-03-22-19
```

Comment: @xbmono: Just consider that accepted answer is invoking `awk` 3 times and then `sed` and `grep` also for this simple task which is done here without invoking any external binary.

Comment: Great code anubhava , you ROCK. We can really learn a lot from you(all experts here).

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
appname=$(echo $x | awk -F_ '{print $1}')
hcode=$(echo $x | awk -F_ '{print $(NF-1)}')
timestamp=$(echo $x | awk -F_ '{print $NF}' | grep -oE '[0-9-]{2,}')
title=$(echo $x | sed "s/.*${appname}_\(.*\)_$hcode.*/\1/")
```

where `x` is the variable containing the filename

hashcode is retrieved by fetching the second last column with _ as delimiter. timestamp is retrieved from the last column and extracting only numbers and - out of it. Title is retrieved by fetching characters between the appname and the hashcode.

Comment: Thanks but this one returns the title as CT-111-some-title-with_underscore-in-it_c37a9a5fc272a5c94009a61ce8dff79900ab9102

Comment: @xbmono : Not sure how you ran it.. when i try, it does give CT-111-some-title-with_underscore-in-it

Comment: yes it's strange I don't know why... but thanks anyway